# How to debug layout constraint issues in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm unable to build an interface I want to build as the objects does not obey the constraints I place on them.

Clarification to this who do not understand the question above:

I want what I see in Xcode on all devices, no matter the constraints on a iPhone 7+ and I assume a 7 and lower the image is either stretched or reshaped.

[iphoneX simulator renders correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShNvJ.png)

[iPhone 7+ with same constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xM21.jpg)

Xcode:

[image: Xcode]

Build:

[image: Build]

Comment: It's not easy understanding auto layout. The best way to understand it is to watch the 4 or 5 videos Apple has made about it  from WWDC conferences.

Comment: You need to provide much more information. What constraints are you setting? Your images don't show anything about what you're trying to do, and what's not working.

Comment: i've watched the layout video and rewatched them. I want them to be 186x186 and look like the build in Xcode no matter the size of the screen... they keep doing weird shapes and different sizes... Also I hate when people downvote just because someone wants to learn, downvotes should be for people who want the work done for them.

Comment: You still need to describe how you are setting your constraints... Have you set width and height constraints? Have you set X and Y constraints?

Comment: I've done a combination of everything. nothing seems to work. I've even linked it to the side and not other objects and still get a wrong variation

Comment: @TechyGod - please review this: [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com//help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you improve the question, to save it from being closed? I don't use XCode or iOS, but I imagine some code or config would be necessary for people to help. See DonMag's remarks, from ~30 hours ago.

Comment: to clarify I don't hate anyone, I hate when others downvote users (most of the time anonymously for nothing more then the fact that they are asking in a non attacking or expecting way). as for rephrasing the question it is straight forward, " no matter the constraints place on the object {image view} it will resize and move the object to some other size or shape."

Comment: Also there is no code involved its a constraints issue.

Comment: You think the question is straight forward because you already know what you mean.  To someone like me, who has no idea what you want, "no matter the constraints place on the object {image view} it will resize and move the object to some other size or shape" is total nonsense.

Comment: The image view is being resized I've said that multiple ways. not only that but i've add multiple pictures showing something thats out of place.

Comment: @TechyGod - you need to show us how your constraints are set. Auto-layout works - it is not a "brand new thing." If your constraints are not doing what you want them to do, then the constraints need to be fixed. Unless we know what those constraints are, we have no way of helping you.

Comment: i've got it to halfway work with aspect ratio and connecting to objects only. I've escalated this to the Apple Code support team... and they are baffled about this.

Comment: @DonMag the reason I did not show the constraints was because I have used every configuration I know of and have researched on the web. Thus why it's now at CodeLevel support.

Comment: @TechyGod - super, so make sure there's no chance anyone around here could possibly offer any help!

Comment: @DonMag not sure I understand? If constraints are not working as detailed in the Auto-layout resources provided by Apple then it's probably something not building right. If you haven't tried every possible way detailed then definetly do that before requesting code level, you'll only get a free one if its a problem on there end. And do post for help first here. (I think that what you were meaning)

Comment: @TechyGod - my point is, if you actually told us what / how you are setting your constrains, ***maybe*** somebody could help you. If it actually *is* a bug, or a problem with your particular system, then by posting your details at least somebody could confirm that it is working correctly on *their* system but not yours. By consistently commenting that you are trying everything, but for whatever reason not telling us what you are trying, you are **making it impossible for anyone here to help you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the answer as it's only affecting me currently. It's been escalated to Code-Level Support, They are sending someone to the team to investigate my mac as even when reinstalling Xcode it should not have or build the problem above. If anyone else is having the trouble above they should use a code-level support request as this is on their end as far as we know about.